# Vite Web Workers failing on dev server

Tags: vite, web-worker

Helloo I'm moving code to a web worker thread on my p5.js project. I have it working but only when I build and preview it (`yarn build && yarn preview`). When using the vite dev server (`yarn dev`) it fails to load.

On the dev server I get `loc is undefined` and `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./rgb-worker.ts', import.meta.url), {
  name: canvasSize,
  type: 'module'
  /* @vite-ignore */
});
```

I have the file as a sibling to the file I'm spawning the worker from. I tried using the public folder as well and it did not work. I can't find any resources to get it working any advice would help !

Answer (score 0):

firefox stable doesn't support module workers yet: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12874

Comment: FIrefox stable started supporting module workers in version 114 in Jun 2023: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#browser_compatibility